# Same scale of geom point size for two separate ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

When we create two separate plot with ggplot, the scale (for the size of geom point for example) is independent.

```
library(ggplot)
library(ggpubr)

df1=data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10,s=1:10)
p1=ggplot(df1,aes(x,y,size=s))+geom_point()

df2=data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10,s=1:10*10)
p2=ggplot(df2,aes(x,y,size=s))+geom_point()


ggarrange(p1,p2)
```

[image]

In this combined graph, we can see that the size of the points appeared to be the same, whereas the value is not the same. Is it possible to fix the scale for the two plots.

One solution is to use `facet_wrap` after `rbind`ing

```
df1$group=1
df2$group=2

ggplot(rbind(df1,df2),aes(x,y,size=s))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~as.factor(group))
```

[image]

**But for some reason, I would not bind the datasets.**

Comment: You can add `+ scale_size_continuous(limits = range(df1$s, df2$s))` to both plots to synchronise the scale limits.